# Javascript rollover button

Tags: javascript, css, button, css-transitions, mouseover

How do I make a button like: http://www.ideabank.pl?

The buttons I'm talking about are the 9 buttons below main banner.

- expand to top on rollover (animated)
- change text

How do I make it?

Comment: You can accomplish the same effect with just CSS as well. If you use javascript, then the script will need to edit the DOM's CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cXSyZ/)

The basic HTML is

```
<div id="box">
    <a href='#'>
        <div class="col_inside">
            <span class="span-inside">Button</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

There is a box containing a linked div. This div becomes the button because it is wrapped within the  tag.

The CSS

```
#box {
    width: 600px;
    height: 240px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
}
.col_inside {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 60px;
    transition: height 0.5s linear;
    background: #0096de;
    text-align: center;
}
.col_inside .span-inside:last-child {
    display: none;
}
.col_inside:hover {
    height: 90px;
}

.col_inside:hover span:first-child {
       display: none;
}

.col_inside:hover span:last-child {
    display: inline-block;
}
.span-inside {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

The part you would be most interested in is

```
.col_inside {
    height: 60px;
    transition: height 0.5s linear;
}
.col_inside:hover {
   height: 90px;
}
```

The transition takes the property you want to apply the transition to, the duration, and the timing-function